# Compare two tables return in printf both

Tags: php, compare, printf

I have this code:

```
{
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comments  ORDER BY date DESC");      
$myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result);

do
{


printf ("
                            <li class=''>               
                    <span class='author'>%s | %s</span>
                    <span class='title'>%s</span>
                    <a href='%s' class='website' title='%s'>Open</a>
                </li>



",$myrow["author"],$myrow["date"],$myrow["title"],$myrow["id"],$myrow["title"],$myrow["link"]);
}


while ($myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result));

}
```

This gives me data from comments table. In comments table there is field named: postid.
How can I use another query to compare comments table and news table? In news table WHERE id=$myrow["postid"] . After I compaer and get the title of news. How can I put that title in printf in my code?

Comment: It may not help answer your question, but you should stop using `mysql_*` functions. They're being deprecated. Instead use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) (supported as of PHP 5.1) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) (supported as of PHP 4.1). If you're not sure which one to use, [read this article](http://www.deprecatedphp.com/mysql_/).

Comment: @Matt Okay. Il try to implent it after i get this solved. The braces is for code belowe it.

Comment: using `printf()` in PHP is pointless unless you're doing formatting on the inserted values. `echo "abc $xyz def"` accomplishes the same thing with far better comprehensibility.

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to perform a `join` using two queries. Check out [this diagram](http://4.bp.blogspot.com/_gWQaU40PH24/TG_d4LWGqYI/AAAAAAAAI0I/szwmLmy2t44/s640/Visual_SQL_JOINS_V2.png). It helped me get a better grasp of `join`s.

Comment: @MarcB even using a close-PHP tag `?>`, and using `<?= $var ?>` where appropriate would be more readable.

Comment: @matt: for multiline, it'd be better to simply use a heredoc, unless you really want to see the html highlighted as well.

Comment: What is the structure of the tables from which you're extracting data?

Comment: NEWS: ID|TITLE|TEXT|DATE|PBY|
COMMENTS: ID|POSTID|PBY|TEXT|DATE|

Comment: How do the two tables relate to each other? What column in table B identifies which row it belongs to in table A? Does `COMMENTS.POSTID` refer to `NEWS.ID`?

Comment: As you did put it. comments.postid refer to news.id. 
p.s. Sorry, Im not that good at English!

Answer (score 0):

**THIS IS NOT AN ANSWER, BUT A CLEANER ALTERNATIVE TO WHAT YOU HAVE WRITTEN ABOVE. PLEASE DO NOT UP-VOTE.**

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comments  ORDER BY date DESC");
$myrow  = mysql_fetch_array($result);
while($myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "
        <li class=''>
            <span class='author'>{$myrow['author']} | {$myrow['date']}</span>
            <span class='title'>{$myrow['title']}</span>
            <a href='{$myrow['id']}' class='website' title='{$myrow['title']}'>Open</a>
        </li>";
}
```

**ALSO NOTE** that `mysql_*` functions are deprecated. PHP has alternatives: `mysqli` and `PDO`. If you're not sure which one to use, [read this article](http://www.deprecatedphp.com/mysql_/).

Comment: Will PDO work if half of my script is in mysql. Like i connect with mysql but get rows with PDO?

Comment: @mypoint No. You'll have to do some refactoring. It shouldn't be anything too major, though. As far as the connection goes, you're only changing one line of code.